# How to deal with not well-formed character in xml file with elementtree in python

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, elementtree

I'm parsing the xml files encoded with `utf-16` using `ElementTree.parse` function.
The program would break down when the file contains some not well-formed characters such as `♀, ♂` .etc. And the error "`xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token)`"occurs.
How could I avoid this error and resolve this problem? How could I just ignore these not well-formed characters? Thanks! below is my code：

```
tree = ElementTree()
root = tree.parse(xml_file)
```

xml_file is the file encoded in UTF-16 format.
The error would point out the line and column number of the not well-formed character.

Comment: You didn't give enough information. Where are the tokens placed? Inside the tags, attributes names, attribute values or element values? Are they between CDATA thingies? Is the file really encoded with UTF-16? If the header set correctly?

Comment: the character is in element values.yes, it is between CDATA thingies.

Comment: @Blubber The xml content is like this: <name id='1'>♂ John</name>

Comment: It is handy if you show in your question the code you wrote so I can elaborate my answer from it.

Comment: @MarcodeWit Thanks for your reply. I have showed my code in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `xml.parsers.expat.ParserCreate` supports only four encodings I would try them all. Those encodings are:
`UTF-8`, `UTF-16`, `ISO-8859-1` (`Latin1`), and `ASCII` .

You can now run `ElementTree.parse` with the encoding like:

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree
from xml.parsers import expat
tree = ElementTree()
root = tree.parse(xml_file, parser=expat.ParserCreate('UTF-8') )
root = tree.parse(xml_file, parser=expat.ParserCreate('UTF-16') )
root = tree.parse(xml_file, parser=expat.ParserCreate('ISO-8859-1') )
root = tree.parse(xml_file, parser=expat.ParserCreate('ASCII') )
```

Comment: could you give more details? some code fragment? @Marco de Wit

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you need to establish.

(a) is there an XML declaration and what does it say about the encoding?

(b) what are the actual bytes in the file used to represent these characters?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. There is an XML declaration at the beginning of the file which indicate the encoding format is UTF_16.